# Filtering + Pagination problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I'm doing some filtering and pagination for a project of mine. I'm using Mixitup and simplePagination to achieve my goal, which is basic filtering based on categories, ASC and DESC sorting and pagination.

But I can't seem to get this code to work

HTML

```
    <button class="sort" data-sort="random">Random</button>
    <button class="sort" data-sort="order:asc">Ascending Order</button>
    <button class="sort" data-sort="order:desc">Descending Order</button>
    <button class="filter" data-filter="all">All</button>
    <button class="filter" data-filter=".video">Ipapers</button>
    <button class="filter" data-filter=".ipaper">Video</button>

    <section id="posts" class="posts-container">
            <article class="mix post post-1 video" data-order="1">
                    <h3>An article</h3>
        <p>Article content</p>
            </article>
            <article class="mix post post-2 ipaper" data-order="2">
                    <h3>An article</h3>
        <p>Article content</p>
            </article>
            <article class="mix post post-3 ipaper" data-order="3">
                    <h3>An article</h3>
        <p>Article content</p>
            </article>
            <article class="mix post post-4 video" data-order="4">
                    <h3>An article</h3>
        <p>Article content</p>
            </article>
            <div id="posts-nav"></div>
    </section>
```

JS:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){

        var items = $(".post");

        var numItems = items.length;
        var perPage = 1;

        items.slice(perPage).hide();
            $('#posts').mixItUp({
                animation: {
                    duration: 400,
                    effects: 'stagger(34ms) translateZ(460px) fade',
                    easing: 'cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1)'
                },
                callbacks: {
                    onMixLoad: function(state){
                        //alert('MixItUp ready... do some pagination!');

                        $("#posts-nav").pagination({
                            items: numItems,
                            itemsOnPage: perPage,
                            onPageClick: function(pageNumber) {
                                var showFrom = perPage * (pageNumber - 1);
                                var showTo = showFrom + perPage;

                                items.hide() 
                                     .slice(showFrom, showTo).show();
                            }
                        });

                    }
                }
            });  
        });
    </script>
```

I'm trying to add on the pagination once the posts have been loaded, that's why I'm trying to paginate once mixItUp has loaded. When loading my site the pagination is shown and so are the posts, but the posts aren't indexed, meaning I first have to click on "next page" before the actual posts per page are working. And when I'm filtering the pagination should redraw/recalculate. Am I using the callback the wrong way?

I have created a fiddle although I can't seem to get it to work, only on my local server: http://jsfiddle.net/x8Lnowkz/1/